# docker mmap Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: docker, mmap, ethernet

My programm can't mmaped memory in docker from ethernet.

```bash
docker run --rm -it -e "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" --network=host snf
```

```c
    int packet_socket = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_IP));
    if (packet_socket == -1) {
        printf("Can't create AF_PACKET socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    int version = TPACKET_V3;
    int setsockopt_packet_version = setsockopt(packet_socket, SOL_PACKET, PACKET_VERSION, &version, sizeof(version));

    if (setsockopt_packet_version < 0) {
        printf("Can't set packet v3 version\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int interface_number = get_interface_number_by_device_name(packet_socket, interface_name);
    if (interface_number == -1) {
        printf("Can't get interface number by interface name\n");
        return -1;
    }

    struct packet_mreq sock_params;
    memset(&sock_params, 0, sizeof(sock_params));
    sock_params.mr_type = PACKET_MR_ALLMULTI;
    sock_params.mr_ifindex = interface_number;

    int set_promisc = setsockopt(packet_socket, SOL_PACKET, PACKET_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (void *) &sock_params, sizeof(sock_params));
    if (set_promisc == -1) {
        printf("Can't enable promisc mode: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_ll bind_address;
    memset(&bind_address, 0, sizeof(bind_address));

    bind_address.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
    bind_address.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_ALL);
    bind_address.sll_ifindex = interface_number;

    struct tpacket_req3 req;
    memset(&req, 0, sizeof(req));

    req.tp_block_size = blocksiz;
    req.tp_frame_size = framesiz;
    req.tp_block_nr = blocknum;
    req.tp_frame_nr = (blocksiz * blocknum) / framesiz;

    req.tp_retire_blk_tov = 60; // Timeout in msec
    req.tp_feature_req_word = TP_FT_REQ_FILL_RXHASH;

    int setsockopt_rx_ring = setsockopt(packet_socket, SOL_PACKET , PACKET_RX_RING , (void *) &req , sizeof(req));
    if (setsockopt_rx_ring == -1) {
        printf("Can't enable RX_RING for AF_PACKET socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    uint8_t* mapped_buffer = NULL;
    struct iovec *rd = NULL;
    mapped_buffer = (uint8_t *) mmap(NULL, req.tp_block_size * req.tp_block_nr, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_LOCKED, packet_socket, 0);
    if (mapped_buffer == MAP_FAILED) {
        printf("mmap failed: %d %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
```

I try to mmap (~128 MB) data from socket in docker. I have two threads, and each thread try to mmaped 64 MB but I got:

```bash
mem: 64 mb per iface; cores: 2 per iface 
mmap failed: 11 Resource temporarily unavailable 
mmap failed: 11 Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I tryed run docker from sudo, start app in docker from root. Same error.
When I started it without docker everything ok.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `docker run` command: `--ulimit memlock=150994944`

That error from `mmap` means you asked for more `MAP_LOCKED` memory than you're allowed to have. The problem is that Docker gives a very low ulimit by default. You can see this by running `ulimit -Sl` and `ulimit -Hl` both inside and outside the container and comparing them (but beware that bash uses kilobytes while Docker expects bytes). The above argument will give you a ulimit of 144MB.

Comment: You can also use it to avoid counting the amount of memory needed. `--ulimit memlock=-1` or `--privileged`. Thx for help.